# BitTorrent Sync - Exclude All Specific Subfolders

Tags: sync, bittorrent, dotfiles, bittorrent-sync

I want to sync up my dev folder including various project folders, each having `node_modules` folder inside. **I would like to exclude all `node_modules` subfolders.**

Here is an example of my file structure:

`.
├── projectOne
│   ├── index.app
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
└── projectTwo
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    └── src`

The root folder has `.SyncIgnore` file for excluding specific folders and files, but I do not know how to exclude ALL `node_modules` subfolders.

`*/node_modules` do not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great reference document: http://antimatrix.org/BTSync/Documentation/BTSync_Notes.html#Using_SyncIgnore_file

You should use either of these to ignore node_modules:

```
# ignore node_modules on every level in hierarchy
node_modules
# ignore node_modules only on the second level
/*/node_modules
```

Comment: Yes, simple `node_modules` solved it. Thank you.

Comment: the link is broken